# How do you capture unix shell error messages?

Tags: shell, unix

I want to catch error messages to display them properly instead of letting them crash in the console

So I'm using redirection 2>&1 in my commands

```
result=$(myInstruction 2>&1)
```

If an error occurs then it is captured in the result variable and I'm able to display it in a clean way

But when I have several commands using pipes I noticed error is crashed into console again

```
result=$(myInstruction1 | myInstruction2 | myInstruction3 2>&1)
```

The only way I found is to do this :

```
result=$((myInstruction1 | myInstruction2 | myInstruction3) 2>&1)
```

Is is the right way ?

Thank you.

Comment: `Is is the right way ?` Sooo does it work?

Comment: Yes it works but I would like to know if it is the correct way

Answer (score 1):

> Is is the right way ?

Yes.

You can also group commands in current shell `{` `}`, instead of a subshell `(` `)`.

Also I would add a space, just for readability to differentiate from `$(( .. ))` arithmetic expansion.

```
 result=$( ( myInstruction1 | myInstruction2 | myInstruction3 ) 2>&1)
 result=$( { myInstruction1 | myInstruction2 | myInstruction3; } 2>&1)
```